# Osmdroid - Marker - increase selection area to get the InfoWindow

Tags: osmdroid

When selecting a Marker an InfoWindow pops up.

Sometimes the selection of a Marker is difficult. Especially when the map is rotating in the direction of navigation.

How can I increase the 'touch circle' so that selection is easier?

Update: I have to change the hitTest() for the Marker by subclassing.

I would like to check whether the 'hit' (or touch) was within a circle of X pixels around the point of the Marker. The icon will rotate while I navigate, so I guess I don't use the icon.

How can I do that?

```
public boolean hitTest(final MotionEvent event, final MapView mapView){
    final Projection pj = mapView.getProjection();
    pj.toPixels(mPosition, mPositionPixels);
    // Does mPositionPixels contains the x, y of the Marker? 
    // Should I draw a Rect around this point, or could it be a circle?
    // How can I check whether the event.getX(), event.getY() is a hit? 
    return hit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method proposed by spy is feasible.

You can also create your icon bitmap with an area of transparent pixels around. This is a very simple way to increase its touch area.

Comment: Adding another icon is in my case not an alternative. Could you expand the above hitTest() method as ... check whether the touch/hit was within X pixels of the center of the Marker? 
AND ... THANK YOU SO MUCH for providing Osmdroid. I enjoy it each week since 4 years via geocaching.

Comment: Ah ... now I understand ;-)
Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Mker would say, extend the Marker class and override the method `hitTest`. That is used for the Marker itself. I'm not sure if you can change this for the InfoWindow itself.

Comment: Can you help a bit further? See my suggestion in the Question.

Comment: Can you give a few hints on how I could put a circle around the marker so that this will be the new touch area? Then I will award this and mark this as the answer.